# Design pattern for ResourceBundle

Tags: oop, design-patterns, bundle

I recently written a `ValidationBundle`, to validate the arguments passed to a method. Validation bundle accepts different types of `Validator`'s. Upon validating the bundle, it invokes each one of the validators registered with the bundle. I was wondering if any pre-existing design pattern is followed or not?

Comment: This sounds like the strategy pattern to me. You should TDD it and let that determine your pattern.

Comment: @CallumLinington Strategy pattern is where one of the algorithm would be selected  depending on the input supplied at runtime but in my case all of the registered validators are being called. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: I missed that part in your question, still TDD should help a lot

Comment: Well, isn't almost like the service locator pattern? You have a bunch of services (the validators) that you're putting in a registry (the bundle). At runtime something will use this registry to get access to all known validation services, used to validate a particular subject (the arguments passed to the method in your case).

Comment: even though there is an apparent similarity to the service locator pattern, this lacks the caching aspect involved in the service locator. ValidatorBundle maintains a list of specific type to which as many specialisation can be added. Invoking the operation on the ValidatorBundle would in turn delegate to behaviour of all the registered subtypes one by one.

Comment: How does a method access a `ValidationBundle`?

Comment: @jaco0646
I'm trying to convey the gist of it in the code below : 

    `public static void method(String ... vargs) {
        Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Driver.class);
        ValidatorBundle validatorBundle = new ValidatorBundle.Builder()
                .withValidator(new DataTypeValidator(vargs))
                .withValidator(new ArgLengthValidator(vargs))
                .build();
        List<ValidationException> results = validatorBundle.validate();
        for(ValidationException e : results){
            LOG.info(e);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the [Builder](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) pattern is obviously used to construct the `ValidatorBundle` and the [Iterator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator) pattern is used to loop through it.

This isn't the typical [Strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) implementation you would see in a tutorial, but assuming there is an abstract `Validator` which is implemented by `DataTypeValidator`, `ArgLengthValidator`, etc., then I think it's fair to label them as "a family of interchangeable algorithms," which qualifies as the Strategy pattern.

Going beyond design patterns, it would be interesting to see this implemented with a different paradigm. Specifically, I think this type of validation could be implemented as a cross-cutting concern with [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).